# Unable to create folder in Google Drive using postman

Tags: google-drive-api, postman

I'm trying to create a new folder using postman but unable to do so. I used the POST method along with https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files (as mentioned in Google docs to create metadata(https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)) along with two Params mimeType and title in body.

I have also tried this with /upload endpoint as well.

Some metadata created not a folder. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

the property now is name in v3 not title but the result is the same for me. it does not create a folder but a file named Untitled and it also does kot use the meta data